# Using wildcard * to complete file name

Tags: vba, email, wildcard, attachment

I'm putting together a VBA code to attach a document to an email, but I only have the first part of the document name to be attached. I've tried using "*" at the end so that it finds the document with what I have, but that's not working. Could anyone help? This is what I have:

```
If EmailType = "KiteWorks" Then

    .Attachments.Add ("File Path (redacted)\Results Enquiry " & AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 2).Value & " " & BatchNumber & "*")

End If
```

(this section is within a with)

I'm testing with a document that is called "Result Enquiry 2 2 [Art].pdf" but I keep getting an error that the name or directory is not valid. I believe the issue is with the wildcard "*" that I hoped would fill in for the "[Art].pdf"

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can use [`Dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) here to determine the file name.

Comment: When you say "first part of the document name" what do you mean by that? Is it the path where the file exists? If not, I am afraid you cannot obtain the file full name. Now, does `AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 2).Value & " " & BatchNumber & "*"` want to build the file name? If yes, do you know its extension, or any extension for the respective path will be good enough? What value does `AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 2)` cell have?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you BigBen for making me realise how silly I was being...

Updated my code to:

```
If EmailType = "KiteWorks" Then

    FilePath = "Path Redacted" & "\Results Enquiry " & AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 2).Value & " " & BatchNumber & "*"
    FileExists = Dir(FilePath)

    If FileExists = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "Could not find PDF of script in scanned folder."
        
    Else

        .Attachments.Add ("Path Redacted" & FileExists)

    End If
    
End If
```

Comment: I am afraid, I cannot understand how the above code works... Does `BatchNumber` variable contain also the extension? In such a case the last "*" is not necessary and you already built the full name without being necessary to use `Dir`... Please, show us what the two not seen variable contains (`AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 2).Value` and `BatchNumber`). Does the file name start with `Results Enquiry` string?

Comment: @FaneDuru BatchNumber does not contain the extension, nor "[Art]". That's why I needed to include the "*". That last part after the batch number, which is just a six digit number, can vary depending on a bunch of different cases that don't matter to me.